# Is is possible to finetune SimCLR on an instance segmentation task using PyTorch Lightning Bolts?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I have a dataset of high-resolution drone images, which I have split into tiles of size 512x512. The tiles will be annotated by delineating a specific type of vegetation and stored in COCO format. I would like to use self-supervised learning for instance segmentation in the tiles. The Pytorch Lightning bolts module provides already pre-trained self-supervised models, such as SimCLR. According to the [bolts module documentation](https://pytorch-lightning-bolts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/self_supervised_models.html), it should be possible to finetune SimCLR on any computer vision task, such as instance segmentation, using bolts.

The only examples I found, however, show how SimCLR is finetuned on classification tasks. How would one finetune SimCLR (or another self-supervised model) on an instance segmentation task?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can use SimCLR as a feature extractor and a deep model for instance segmentation based on the obtained data representation from the SimCLR (instead of data in normal cases).